# Asp.Net How can I pass parameters using an 'IN' clause in the query to refine a search

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, web, webmatrix

I'm following Mikes post on the IN Clause on http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/156/webmatrix-database-helpers-for-in-clauses but I'm having trouble adding additional params. As per his post, I started with some checkboxes for the categories and worked fine but I added some other checkboxes for the brands but it's not working. I'm not sure how to pass additional params to the in clause.

The idea of what I want to accomplish is to have a side bar with different product filters (categories, brands, age, price, etc) and as the user clicks it will update the results. Can someone please help me on this one?

This is the code i'm working with but this gives errors:

```
// for the categories
var cTemp = Request["categoryId"].Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var cParms = cTemp.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
var cIn = string.Join(",", cParms);

// for the brands
var bTemp = Request["brandId"].Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var bParms = bTemp.Select((s, i) => "@" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
var bIn = string.Join(",", bParms);

var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductID, J.CategoryID, J.BrandID, P.ProductName, P.Price, " +
       "FROM Products P " +
       "JOIN Junction J ON J.ProductID = P.ProductID " +
       "WHERE J.CategoryID IN ({0}) OR J.BrandID IN ({1})";

var products = db.Query(String.Format(sql, cIn, bIn), cTemp, bTemp);
```

Comment: what are the errors you are seeing?

Comment: This is what the cTemp, cParms, cIn returns:
cTemp: System.String[]
cTemp:: 1 

cParms: System.String[]
cParms:: @0 

cIn: @0

Comment: This is the error i'm getting: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from DbType System.String[] to a known SqlCeType. Line 59: var products = db.Query(String.Format(sql, cIn, bIn), cTemp, bTemp);

Comment: @alvin : try removing cTemp, bTemp from Query method call.

Comment: @Dark Knight that's giving me an error on that line: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 247,Token in error = WHERE ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Inspect the value of `String.Format(sql, cIn, bIn)` - make it a separate string variable. You will see that you have duplicate parameter names in this SQL expression: @0, @1, etc.
2. When calling `db.Query`, do:

`db.Query(<final sql statement>, allTemp)`

where `allTemp` is concatenation of `cIn` and `bIn`.

Item 2 is the cause of the error that you see.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you show me please

Comment: what specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @alvin: After you define your `sql` variable, add the line `var tmp = String.Format(sql, cIn, bIn);`. Set a breakpoint at that line (or just after it) and look at the value of `tmp`. I think what @Igor is saying is that you'll find it contains `@0` etc defined twice, so you'll probably only load in the values from `cTemp` into both `IN` statements. `bTemp` will likely be ignored, or at least confuse things. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

For the error you mentioned in the comment, try removing parameters from `db.Query` method.you are passing string array to sql parameters,which is not correct. Your method call should be this.

```
var products = db.Query(String.Format(sql, cIn, bIn));
```

I think there is also error in your `WHERE` clause handling. Try something like this..

```
var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductID, J.CategoryID, J.BrandID, P.ProductName, P.Price, " +
       "FROM Products P " +
       "JOIN Junction J ON J.ProductID = P.ProductID ";

var whereClause = ""
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cIn)||!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bIn))
{
    whereClause = "WHERE";
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cIn))
    {
        whereClause+=" J.CategoryID IN ({0}) ";
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bIn))
        whereClause+=" OR ";
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bIn))
    {
        whereClause+=" J.BrandID IN ({1}) ";
    }
}
sql = sql+whereClause;
```

Comment: The OP is using parameterized sql statement - he MUST pass parameter values to `db.Query`.

Comment: This confused me at first too. The result of the `String.Format` is something like `@0, @1, @2...`. These are the expected parameters that need to be passed in, which are supplied via cTemp and bTemp. They're not the values themselves.